# implementing autocomplete in my website

Tags: autocomplete, search-box

i am developing a website where i intend to provide the search feature. I am developing it in PHP/MYSQL and i have written the script to perform the search. I wish to provide autocomplete or suggested searches option in the search box as the user types, can i know what are my choices and how can i make use of them?

I had tried YUI Autocomplete, it looks good to me, however i do not understand when it says using a local proxy for the datasource. Can any one help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider trying the [Scriptaculous autocomplete](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter).  It's very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

what does it exactly say on the documentation? (can you provide a link)

by local proxy I would think it means a proxy to a remote web service or API on another domain. (you can't make requests unless scripts are executed on the same domain). http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

I used [jQuery autocompletex](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autocompletex)